# Mandrill not sent attachments and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, email-attachments, mandrill

I'm sending messages using the Mandrill API in JS code, including base64-encoded background images.

HTML:

```
..........    
<div id="image" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,wFEFefFEFW........");">
..........
```

JS:

```
var image_1 = $('#image').css('background-image'); //image base64 encoded
image_1 = image_1.replace('url("data:image/png;base64,','').replace('")','');
subject = 'text';
subject += '<img src="cid:image_1">';
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
    data: {
        'key': '*******',
        'message': {
            ................
            'html': subject + '<br />'
        },
       'images' : [{
           'type' : 'image/png',
           'name' : 'image_1',
           'content' : image_1
       }]
.....................
```

My messages are delivered, but without images.

I've also tried including the images as attachments. This doesn't work either: I get no attachments.

```
'attachments' : [{
    'type' : 'image/png',
    'name' : 'image_1',
    'content' : image_1
}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: problem is solved. Images and attachments arrays must be in message array.